# ReacJs: "Warning: Expected `onChange` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-state-management

i have this problem triying to pass a handler function to a component in react. Im use Eslint and Create-react-app. Im triying to use ()=> and event => handle(event) and cant do. this is the code:

```
      
     setNewName(event.target.value)}
  
  const [newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState('')
   

  const handleNewNumber =(event) => {
        setNewNumber(event.target.value)
    }
```

```
        <div>
        name: <input
        defaultValue = {newName}
        onChange={ handleNameChange}
    />
     <div>
         number: <input
         value = {newNumber}
         onChange = {handleNewNumber}
       />
     </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
      </div></form>
```

Comment: Could you add in the complete code for the component. What you have currently doesn't really show what the issue is. Where is `handleNameChange`, for example? Why are you immediately setting `setNewName(event.target.value)}` when there is no state available at that point?

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to pass the event to the function

```
      <div>
         number: <input
         value = {newNumber}
         onChange = {(e) => handleNewNumber(e)}
      />
```

Comment: With `onChange={handleNewNumber}` the event is implied and will be passed to the function as the first argument.